# When receiving a `payout.created` Stripe webhook, what is the easiest way to determine which Stripe Connect Custom account it is for?

Tags: stripe-payments

(Stripe api version: 2020-08-27)

I am working on setting up Stripe to create payouts automatically each week to our Stripe Connect accounts with earnings.

I want my own api to listen for the `payout.created` Stripe webhook, so I can record and track the event data in my local database. However, I don't see any easy way to tell which Stripe Connect account the newly created payout is for, by looking at the object's properties ([API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/object)).

I was going to try and make the determination by looking at the `$payout->destination` property, which would give me the bank account the payout was for. I could then retrieve that bank account and see which user it relates to. However, in order to retrieve a bank account, I [have to already know the customer id](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_bank_accounts/retrieve), and I don't have that info. I'm not even dealing with a customer here, I'm dealing with a service provider that has earnings that we need to pay. The bank account is not the same thing as the stripe connect account.

How do I deal with this? Seems weird that it would be so difficult to figure out who the payout is for.

Comment: Events emitted from connected accounts should contain an `account` property that holds the account ID of the event's source: https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-account

Comment: Ah, so that is what the "Endpoints receiving events from Connect applications" is for. All this time I never knew that. Thanks.